# Phonegap application not working with android 4.0

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have created a application using Phonegap 2.9.0 .The Build which is running all the android phone version less than 4.0. When i instal in Android 4+ devices it shows blank screen.The same build works fine with ios all versions.Here the **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang=en-US>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=Cache-control content=no-cache />
    <meta name=format-detection content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/sencha-touch.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" />
    <link href="resources/css/mobiscroll.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="libraries/sencha/sencha-touch-all.js" defer></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery/jquery.1.10.1.js" defer></script>
    <script src="libraries/mobiscroll/mobiscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="app/views/app.js" defer></script>
    <script src="app/views/JSfunctions.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Here the explore snap

[image]

What change requires to run in android 4.0+ devices.Pelase help me to solve this issue

Comment: do you change the cordova.js and add cordova-2.9.0.jar

Comment: i didn't get you, Please explain

Comment: in libs folder you need to add cordova-2.9.0.jar

Comment: @AmitPrajapati its already there.Please see my updated image in question

Comment: yaa do you have also change cordova.js for ios to andorid

Comment: AmitPrajapati asking are you using android version of cordova.js ?.. you should use android version of cordova.js in android and ios version of cordova.js in ios.

Comment: yeah after changing its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang=en-US>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=Cache-control content=no-cache />
        <meta name=format-detection content="telephone=no"/>
        <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/sencha-touch.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" />
        <link href="resources/css/mobiscroll.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="libraries/sencha/sencha-touch-all.js" defer></script>
        <script src="libraries/jquery/jquery.1.10.1.js" defer></script>
        <script src="libraries/mobiscroll/mobiscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="app/views/app.js" defer></script>
        <script src="app/views/JSfunctions.js" defer></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! But no response..I just changed the folder of cordova.js . its working fine now